# Images from URL not displaying in Android react native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Why do my images not appear when I run the application on my mobile device? I've simply followed this tutorial and added a few lines of code: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html.

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA = [
  {title: 'Title', year: '2015', posters: {thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}},
];

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
        <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
        <Image source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: add width height property to style of the image

Comment: That worked ``<Image style={{width: 60, height: 60}} source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}} />``!

Answer (score 0):

Image appears when the width and height properties are set.

```
<Image style={{width: 60, height: 60}} source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https instead http. It could be the main problem.